# Configuring ssl connection for MongoDB in Doctrine on Symfony

Tags: mongodb, ssl, doctrine, symfony

I am struggling to figure out how to configure a connection in Symfony to an ssl-enabled Mongo database with `--sslCAFile <file>` or `--sslAllowInvalidCertificates`. I can successfully connect via shell using the following command:

```
mongo --ssl --sslAllowInvalidCertificates <host>:<port>/<db_name> -u <username> -p<password>
```

Now, how do I convert this into a `doctrine_mongodb` config? I find that setting `ssl: true` might work but can't find anywhere a documentation for setting `--sslAllowInvalidCertificates` or `--sslCAFile <file>`.

Here's what I got so far but it won't work because of the missing flag:

```
doctrine_mongodb:
connections:
    default:
        server: <connection_string>
        username: <username>
        password: <password>
        options:
            ssl: true
```

Adding `sslAllowInvalidCertificates: true` to the options object throws an error - Doctrine doesn't know that field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this isn't possible in the current version of Doctrine MongoDB bundle ([3.2.1](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/releases/tag/3.2.1)). As commented [here](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/issues/380#issuecomment-257157786), the implementation doesn't support passing the driver options to the MongoClient constructor and the [config schema](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/blob/3.2.1/Resources/config/schema/mongodb-1.0.xsd) doesn't support creating [stream context](http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.connecting.ssl.php).

Answer (score 0):

This is now available in the Master branch and will be included in stable branch soon :)
https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/pull/397